# Flags: disputed vs declined

Tags: support, moderation, flagging

Just curious as to the difference between a disputed and a declined flag.

Saw this on my page today:

> 121   deemed helpful
>     1 declined
>     3 disputed

Comment: I think that means that the moderators didn't agree with 1 flag, while for 3 others community members raised different/conflicting flags, but you'd be best off checking the main stackexchange meta for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an identical question on Meta.SE: [What is the difference between disputed and declined flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/what-is-the-difference-between-disputed-and-declined-flags)

Quoting its accepted answer:

> **Declined flag**: if the flag was reviewed by a moderator who did not agree with you (for other, spam, offensive and comments flags) they decline them. Flagging to close a question or as duplicated will push the flag to the close review queue, and if the review is completed without any user casting a close vote the flag is declined. When flagging NAA and VLQ on answers, if none of the reviewers agree with you is shown as declined.
>
> Having too many declined flags leads to a warning, or even a temporary [flag ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/).
>
> [**Disputed flag**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag): When you flag an answer as NAA or VLQ and the post doesn't result in deletion but someone recommended deletion, the flag is disputed. Spam and offensive flags on post that are rolled back are also disputed.
>
> Disputed flags are considered neutral; they do not count toward flag ban.
>
> Although there is no visible flag weight anymore, something alike is kept in the backend to help ordering the flags by importance. The flag weight is decreased by declined flags, but not by disputed ones.

Answer (score 1):

Various flags generally account go to different places to be handled. Flags that ask for questions to be closed go to the close vote queues, as such with posts that are flagged as Not an Answer, or Very Low Quality. These posts go to the respective queues. *This answer is based on flags that go to the review queues, but are not handled by diamond moderators (those can only be made declined, or helpful).*

#### Declined flags

A flag is marked declined usually when all members that had handled the post in the queue disagree with the flag. It might look like this:

[image]

That flag ended up as declined.

#### Disputed flags

You can take this fairly literally. Disputed flags is when the post has various votes, such as "Leave open", or "Close". A nice thing to note is that disputed flags don't count against you, and they are not the same thing as a declined flag at all. This is to show that the outcome wasn't "directly" helpful, but that the outcome was mixed, or disputed.